# Select2 webforms not binding after returned result with ajax "no results found"

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, webforms, jquery-select2

I am returning the result for the researched item or items as json from the back end but the select2 can't seem to append it.
there is no console errors.
here's my code if enyone can help! thanks.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetResults(string q)
    {
        List<Select2Model> list = new List<Select2Model>();

        //geting the data to be searched into a list

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q)))
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.text.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { items = list });
    }
```

and here is my front-end code

```
 $("#<%=DDL_NAME.ClientID%>").select2({
        //placeholder: "Search for item",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/page.aspx/GetResults") %>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                    return  JSON.stringify({ q: params.term });
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processResults: function (data) {
                return { results: data.items };
            }
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution For those who are searching for this error:

server side:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetResults(string q)
    {
        List<Select2Model> list = new List<Select2Model>();

        //geting the data to be searched into a list
        list = (from DataRow row in _cotalog.Rows
                select new Select2Model
                {
                    id = row["CODE"].ToString(),
                    text = row["LABEL"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q)))
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.text.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { results = list, pagination = new { more = true } }); ;
    }
```

Client Side:

```
 $("#<%=DDL.ClientID%>").select2({
        placeholder: "Search for item",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax:
        {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/page.aspx/GetResults") %>',
            data: function (params) {
                return JSON.stringify({ q: params.term });
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                //console.log(JSON.parse(data.d).results);
                return { results: JSON.parse(data.d).results };
            }
        }
    });
```

In case you also want the model:

```
public class Select2Model
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```